# How to match different scenarios with regex in c# and groups

Tags: c#, regex

I want to match  these different scenarios  with a regex pattern. Mainly delimiter is #:

- 1234-1111-234.011#333  => [id = 1234-1111-234.011 and code =333]
- whatever text before 1234-1111-234.011#333 => [textb=whatever text before, id = 1234-1111-234.011 , code =333, texta="]
- 1234-1111-234.011#333 whatever text after => [ textb="" id = 1234-1111-234.011 ,code =333 , texta=whatever text after]
- Text can be both at the beginning or the end
- In every case code can contain also a postfix letter W like 1234-1111-234.011#333W => code=333E
- textb = text with length maximum 15 characters. Only letters and
  numbers.
- id = 17 character long with this format XXXX-XXXX-XXX.XXX   code - 3
  or 4 character long based on W letter is presenting or not
- texta = text with length maximum 15 characters. Only letters and
  numbers.

I am trying to match these scenarios with this piece of code and groups

```
pattern ="
    ?(<textb>[\w\s]{15})#
    ?(<id>[\d\s]{17,17})#
    (?<code>([A-Z]{0,1}\d{2,3}))
    (?<wo>[W]{1})
    ?(<texta>[\w\s]{15})"
```

and

```
  var textb = Regex.Match(mytext, pattern).Groups["textb"].Value;    
  var id= Regex.Match(mytext, pattern).Groups["id"].Value;
  var code= Regex.Match(mytext, pattern).Groups["code"].Value;
  var wo= Regex.Match(mytext, pattern).Groups["wo"].Value;
  var texta= Regex.Match(mytext, pattern).Groups["texta"].Value;
```

A full example is "This is before text 234-1111-234.011#333E This is next text"
Not matching at all.

Comment: What does the input look like? Regular expressions are probably the wrong tool for complex formats

Comment: I know but there is a case I need to do this.The input is like this This is before text 234-1111-234.011#333E This is next text with or without the texts before and after

Comment: Regex is only going to match if the entire pattern matches.  So once the pattern doesn't match none of the groups are valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with one regular expression and then use `Groups` to get the parts you need.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var input = "Before text 1234-1111-234.011#333E After text";
    var pattern = @"(?<btext>[\w ]{0,15})(?<id>[\d\-\.]{17})#(?<code>[\d]{2,3})(?<wo>[A-Z]?)(?<atext>[\w ]{0,15})";
    
    var matches = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
    
    var btext = matches.Groups["btext"];
    var wo = matches.Groups["wo"];
    
    Console.WriteLine(btext.Value);
    Console.WriteLine(wo.Value);

    // etc.
}
```

```
(?<btext>[\w ]{0,15}) // Match letters, numbers and spaces, minimum 0 chars, maximum 15 chars
(?<id>[\d\-\.]{17})   // match numbers, '-' and '.'. Must be 17 chars
#                     // Match pound sign
(?<code>[\d]{2,3})    // Match numbers 2 or 3 chars long
(?<wo>[A-Z]?)         // Match optional letter after code
(?<atext>[\w ]{0,15}) // Match letters, numbers and spaces, minimum 0 chars, maximum 15 chars
```